# Include long text inside Cytoscape.js nodes

Tags: cytoscape.js, cytoscape

I need to create an oriented graph that simulate a conversation. Is it possible to create such a graph with Cytoscape.js?

I would need something like:

```
elements: [
  {data: {id: '1', content:'Hi, I am John ...'}},
  {data: {id: '2', content:'Hi, I am Max ...'}},
  {data:{id: '1_2', source: '1', target: '2' }}
],
```

And then the `content` to be displayed inside the node:

[image]

Comment: is it `content:` or `label:` ?

Comment: oh, i found it, can be sepecified in `elements { styles:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to set `text-wrap` to `wrap` and then you can create multi-line labels by using `\n` in the label. For example: setting label to `Hello\nWorld` will be rendered as

`Hello
 World`

Here is an example: https://jsbin.com/galokipuqu/1

Also see the documentation [for more details](http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/labels).

P.S: Max is the main developer of Cytoscape.js :)

Comment: is it `content:` or `label:` ?

Comment: oh, i found it, can be sepecified in `elements { styles:`